# Creating a sorting algorithm that will sort multiple string values, in a while loop, in a certain order in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have been tasked with creating a sorting algorithm that will take information over somebody and sort it into a certain order. The data is listed in the text file as shown below.

Basically I must sort by one condition and then the next until it is all sorted

At the moment I have created a code that reads the lines and puts each bit of information into separate strings. This is where my problem begins. Now that I have separated them all to sort, I need to find a way to modify a quicksort, or other sorting algorithm to start sorting based off the first string, and adjust them all according, then by the second if they are the same and so on. I am relatively new to creating any kind of sorting algorithm so if anybody would be able to help me atleast get started in the right direction it would be much appreciated. Below is a copy of what I have so far.

```
#include <Header.h>

int main()
{
int n;

string first;
string last;
string street;
string city;
string state;
string zip;

string line;

cout<<"Choose a file size\n 100 \n 200 \n 5000 \n 1000 \n";
cin>>n;
    if (n==100){
        ifstream input("address100.txt"); //Reads lines and pushes to citizens
        while (getline(input, line)){
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, first, '|');
        getline(ss, last, '|');
        getline(ss, street, '|');
        getline(ss, zip, '|');
        getline(ss, city, '|');
        getline(ss, state, '|');
        }
    }
    if (n==200){
        ifstream input("address200.txt"); //Reads lines and pushes to citizens
        while (getline(input, line)){
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, first, '|');
        getline(ss, last, '|');
        getline(ss, street, '|');
        getline(ss, zip, '|');
        getline(ss, city, '|');
        getline(ss, state, '|');
    }
    }
    if (n==1000){
        ifstream input("address1000.txt"); //Reads lines and pushes to citizens
        while (getline(input, line)){
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, first, '|');
        getline(ss, last, '|');
        getline(ss, street, '|');
        getline(ss, zip, '|');
        getline(ss, city, '|');
        getline(ss, state, '|');
    }
    }
    if (n==5000){
        ifstream input("address5000.txt"); //Reads lines and pushes to citizens
        while (getline(input, line)){
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, first, '|');
        getline(ss, last, '|');
        getline(ss, street, '|');
        getline(ss, zip, '|');
        getline(ss, city, '|');
        getline(ss, state, '|');
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any sorting code in your question. Why not just use `std::sort`?

Comment: you should start with defining a structure that contains all the fields and then create a container of such structures. Then use `std::sort`

Comment: Are you trying to write a sorting algorithm as a learning exercise, or are you just trying to write some C++ that will do your required sorting. If its the latter then you can/should use one of the stl sorting algorithms. You then would need to write a comparison function that will compare 2 of your records (return true if first given value should appear first in sorted order).

Comment: If you don't like `std::sort`, you can use the `qsort()` function.

Comment: You are reading in the data but not storing it.   I recommend you declare a `struct` with the fields, then use `std::vector` to contain the records.

Comment: Stop vandalizing your question...

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is that you use a `struct` or `class` to *model* the formatted data.  Each text line will be referred to as a *record*.

```
struct Record  
{
  string first;
  string last;
  string street;
  string city;
  string state;
  string zip;
};
```

Next, you should overload `operator>>` to read in a record:

```
struct Record  
{
  string first;
  string last;
  string street;
  string city;
  string state;
  string zip;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};
 
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    std::string line;
    getline(input, line);
    stringstream ss(line);
    getline(ss, r.first, '|');
    getline(ss, r.last, '|');
    getline(ss, r.street, '|');
    getline(ss, r.zip, '|');
    getline(ss, r.city, '|');
    getline(ss, r.state, '|');
    return input;
}
```

Your input code could look like this:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (input >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

*Note:  input code was copied from OP's question and not verified for correctness.*

**Edit 1: Sorting**
To sort the database, you would write a custom ordering function or define `operator<`.

```
struct Record
{
  // Same as above
  bool operator<(const Record& r) const;
};

bool Record::operator<(const Record& r) const
{
//zip, then city, street, first name, and finally last name.
  if (zip != r.zip) return zip < r.zip;
  else
  {
     if (city != r.city) return city < r.city;
     else
     {
        // Etc.
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Sorting the database is accomplished by:

```
std::sort(database.begin(), database.end());
```

Comment: overloading the operator< assumes that this is the only (or at least the default) sort order. That might be correct of course, but if the sort order is specific to the collection being sorted then a 2-parameter comparison operator can used with the overload of sort that also takes a comparison function as an argument.

Comment: @ROX it doesnt assume that is the only sort order. It assumes that it is the default sort order. The presence of `operator<` does not prohibit calling sort with a different comparator