# Printing a sorted vector list

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, cout

recently I asked for help fixing a code that would sort vectors into a certain order and then sort based off multiple variables, if those vectors were the same. I have got this code to work (I think) but have not been able to get it to print to check this. As it stands, here is the code. I can confirm that everything works, except for the sorting. Because of this I would like to know what a good way to check the sorted list would be.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


struct citizen  { //Struct to separate all variables
  string first;
  string last;
  string street;
  string city;
  string state;
  string zip;
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, citizen& r);
  bool operator<(const citizen& r) const;
};
istream& operator>>(istream& input, citizen& r){//Read file and move all to struct
    string line;
    getline(input, line);
    stringstream ss(line);
    getline(ss, r.first, '|');
    getline(ss, r.last, '|');
    getline(ss, r.street, '|');
    getline(ss, r.zip, '|');
    getline(ss, r.city, '|');
    getline(ss, r.state, '|');
    return input;
}
bool citizen::operator<(const citizen& r) const
{
  if (state != r.state) return state < r.state;
  else
  {
     if (zip != r.zip) return zip < r.zip;
     else
     {
         if (city != r.city) return city < r.city;
         else
         {
             if (street != r.street) return street < r.street;
             else
             {
                 if (first != r.first) return first < r.first;
                 else
                 {
                     if (last != r.last) return last < r.last;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
  }
  return false;
}

int main(){
    clock_t start, end;
        double cpu_time_used;
        start = clock();

    int count=0;
    ifstream input("address100.txt");
    vector<citizen> database;
    citizen r;
    while (input >> r)
    {
        database.push_back(r);
    }
    sort(database.begin(), database.end());
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout<<cpu_time_used<<endl;;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought the question looked familiar :) I see the code you have here is adapted from an answer to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266866/creating-a-sorting-algorithm-that-will-sort-multiple-string-values-in-a-while-l). While the questions themselves are fine, getting help at every stage is not going to help you in the long term.

Answer (score 4):

To print the collection of `citizen`s, you can implement:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, citizen const & r)
{
  output << state;
  // ... etc
  return output;
}
```

where you print each member variable in `citizen`.

Then you can print the collection like this:

```
for(auto const & c : database)
  std::cout << c;
```

---

A simpler way to implement the comparison correctly would be:

```
bool citizen::operator<(citizen const & r) const
{
  return std::tie(state, zip, city, street, first, last) 
       < std::tie(r.state, r.zip, r.city, r.street, r.first, r.last);
}
```

---

From c++20, if you order the members according to how they should be compared, you can let the compiler generate the comparisons for you:

```
struct citizen  
{
  // members in order
  string state;
  string zip;
  string city;
  string street;
  string first;
  string last;

  friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, citizen const & r);

  // generate all relational operators
  auto operator<=>(citizen const &) const = default;  
};
```